# Django template not found in main project directory error

Tags: python, django, templates

I am getting a 'template not found' error, although I've set up a correct template hierarchy  (or so I thought)

```
.
├── manage.py
├── twinja
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
└── twinjasite
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── settings.py
    ├── settings.py~
    ├── settings.pyc
    ├── static
    │   └── twinja
    │       ├── fonts
    │       │   └── bootstrap
    │       │       ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
    │       │       ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
    │       │       ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
    │       │       ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
    │       │       └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
    │       ├── images
    │       ├── javascripts
    │       │   ├── bootstrap
    │       │   │   ├── affix.js
    │       │   │   ├── alert.js
    │       │   │   ├── button.js
    │       │   │   ├── carousel.js
    │       │   │   ├── collapse.js
    │       │   │   ├── dropdown.js
    │       │   │   ├── modal.js
    │       │   │   ├── popover.js
    │       │   │   ├── scrollspy.js
    │       │   │   ├── tab.js
    │       │   │   ├── tooltip.js
    │       │   │   └── transition.js
    │       │   ├── bootstrap.js
    │       │   ├── bootstrap.min.js
    │       │   └── bootstrap-sprockets.js
    │       └── stylesheets
    │           ├── framework.css
    │           └── styles.css
    ├── templates
    │   └── twinja
    │       ├── base.html
    │       └── menu.html
    ├── urls.py
    ├── urls.py~
    ├── urls.pyc
    ├── views.py
    ├── views.py~
    ├── views.pyc
    ├── wsgi.py
    └── wsgi.pyc
```

At first I set up `templates/base` but that did not work. So I made it as you see here: `templates/twinja/base`

Ideally I'm setting up the MAIN template files which are independent of apps, which I thought was meant to go in the main folder (where settings.py is) but perhaps I am mistake.

Yes, I have 'twinja' set up in installed apps as well.

What appears to be wrong here?

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
twinja/base.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your template is independent of apps, it shouldn't be in your app folder - namespace it accordingly.

How do you load your template? Did you setup your `templates`/`static`folders in your `settings.py`?

**Updated**.

For the fresh project you need to configure your `settings.py` file. Read [**here**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/), ask away if you still have a question.

**Updated**.

After you get familiar with static files and how to manage those, spend some time [**here**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/templates/).

Comment: No, I'm using default settings.py with the exception of a database added.